# Android: file not found when decoding bitmap with uri or filepath

Tags: android, path, bitmapfactory

My app allows users to take photos using an external camera activity as part of some data collection, and stores the resulting filepath's Uri.toString() in the model for later use.

When viewing the collections later in a recycler view, the app would slow down due to the size of the images loaded so I implemented Google's solution [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), however I'm getting `FileNotFoundExceptions` in the stack trace, and the images aren't loading. The rest of the view loads fine and the app isn't crashing.

As mentioned, the `uriString` is a string in the format of `content:foo/bar`. I've attempted solutions including.

- Storing `file.getabsolutePath()` instead of `uri.toString` in the model. This changes the uriString format to `file:/foo/bar` and still doesn't work
- Calling `Uri.parse(uriString).getPath()`
- Creating a new File object from the `uriString` and calling `getAbsolutePath()`, and `getPath()` from it.

To be clear, calling `imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(this.item.getPhotoURI()));` absolutely works. So the file exists and the uriString can be interpreted by Android. Function in question is below. With my stack trace underneath.

```
private Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String uriString, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {

        // First we do this just to check dimensions (apparently)
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;


        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uriString, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // And then return with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uriString, options);

    }
```

And my Stack trace:

```
11-24 16:10:57.762 17199-17199/uk.mrshll.matt.accountabilityscrapbook E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/uk.mrshll.matt.accountabilityscrapbook/files/Pictures/JPEG_20161124_160913_-1155698030.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: The filename might be the problem. JPEG_20161124_160913_-1155698030.jpg notice the dash before the start of 11556...0, try to avoid using dashes anywhere in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

> As mentioned, the uriString is a string in the format of content:foo/bar.

Not according to your error. Your error shows that you are trying to pass `"file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/uk.mrshll.matt.accountabilityscrapbook/files/Pictures/JPEG_20161124_160913_-1155698030.jpg"` to `decodeFile()`. The scheme represented on that string is `file`, not `content`. More importantly, `decodeFile()` does not take a `Uri` (or a string representation of a `Uri`), but rather a file path, and file paths do not have schemes.

If you are expecting to have some mix of `content` and `file` schemes:

- Hold onto the `Uri` (or, worst-case, re-parse the `Uri` out of the string)
- Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content represented by the `Uri` (as `openInputStream()` supports both `content` and `file` schemes)
- Use `decodeStream()` instead of `decodeFile()`

Comment: Sorry. That was a different stack trace, as mentioned in my post I tried swapping out how the urlString was created. Attempting your advice re ContentResolver